# How can I build Qt6 for buildroot?

Tags: qt, buildroot, qt6

How can I build a Qt6 application for Buildroot ? I tried a lot to build Qt6 for Buildroot but I was unable to built it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt6 support was not added to Buildroot yet. However, an [RFC series was posted some time ago](https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/project/buildroot/cover/20210213174013.32584-1-ps.report@gmx.net/). Feel free to try it out, comment on it, or improve it and re-post.